# How to use dynamic values in $nin to filter elements from lookup in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 collections

CollectionA

```
[{id:1,name:A},{id:2,name:B},{id:3,name:C},{id:4,name:D},{id:5,name:E}]
```

CollectionB

```
[{aid:2,product:X,date:2009-11-09},{aid:4,product:Y,date:2009-11-09},{aid:3,product:Y,date:2009-11-08}]
```

I want to create an aggregate that will return all elements in A that does not have an aid in B.

Expected Result:

```
[{id:1,name:A},{id:3,name:C},{id:5,name:E}]
```

This is what I tried

```
CollectionB.aggregate([    
        {
            $match: {date : {$gte: "2009-11-09T00:00:00.000Z" ,$lt: "2009-11-09T23:59:59.999Z"} }
        },
        { $lookup: {
            from: "CollectionA",
            let: {
                aid: "$aid"
            },
            pipeline: [
              { $match: {
                  $expr: { 
                      $not: [ { $eq: [ "$$aid", "$id" ] } ] 
                   }
              } }
            ],
            as: "result"
          } 
        },
], function (err, result) {}
```

Is this possible only in the application layer?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following Aggregate query (The difference is you can aggregate to a `CollectionA` instead of `CollectionB`):

```
db.getCollection('CollectionA').aggregate([
{
    "$lookup":   // Run a $lookup to join these two collections
    {
       "from": "CollectionB",
       "localField": "id",
       "foreignField": "aid",
       "as": "combinedResults"
     }
},
{ 
    "$match" : {
        "combinedResults" : [] // Filter the result for which the aid wasn't found
    }
}
])

//Voila! Hope this helps!
```

Comment: Thanks ..it actually helped.